# How do you install Fabric Composer for a multi-user development and production environment

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Can you install Fabric Composer for a multi-user development and production environment.  Seems like you can using the --connectionProfileName, -p  option on the CLI but I could not find where that is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Connection Profiles are described here:
https://fabric-composer.github.io/reference/connectionprofile.html

You should create a connection profile for your remote Fabric, and then deploy your business network archive to it. This will add a "networks" section to your connection profile, which can then be shared with team members that need access to the remote Fabric.

Note: I just noticed that this page needs to be updated, all references to "concerto" should be replaced with "composer".